# Date to String with pattern problem

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to convert DateTime object by some pattern to string of following pattern.

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"


    /// yyyy - the year as in 2005
    /// yy   - the year as in 05, leading zero if necessary
    /// MM   - the month with two digits, leading zero if necessary
    /// dd   - the day of the month with two digits, leading zero if ncessary
    /// HH   - the hour of the day in 24 hours format, leading zero if necessary
    /// mm   - the minute of the hour with two digits, leading zero if necessary
    /// ss   - the second of the minute with two digits, leading zero if necessary
    /// fff  - the fraction of the second with three digits, leading zero if necessary
```

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this van be done with

```
String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff}", yourdatetime);
```

Comment: what does mean 0: before the pattern ?

Comment: The zero corresponds to the argument list after the comma, the zero will be placed by the zero-th element in the agrument list in the format specified after the colon.  Ex:  String.Format("{0} : {1}", 10,12) would output "10 : 12"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `DateTime.ToString(pattern)`. You can see the possible [pattern values here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);

String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", dt);  // "8 08 008 2008"   year
String.Format("{0:M MM MMM MMMM}", dt);  // "3 03 Mar March"  month
String.Format("{0:d dd ddd dddd}", dt);  // "9 09 Sun Sunday" day
String.Format("{0:h hh H HH}",     dt);  // "4 04 16 16"      hour 12/24
String.Format("{0:m mm}",          dt);  // "5 05"            minute
String.Format("{0:s ss}",          dt);  // "7 07"            second
String.Format("{0:f ff fff ffff}", dt);  // "1 12 123 1230"   sec.fraction
String.Format("{0:F FF FFF FFFF}", dt);  // "1 12 123 123"    without zeroes
String.Format("{0:t tt}",          dt);  // "P PM"            A.M. or P.M.
String.Format("{0:z zz zzz}",      dt);  // "-6 -06 -06:00"   time zone
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string answer = new DateTime(2010, 3, 26, 7, 30, 26).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```