# How can I convert a date to this particular string representation?

Tags: string-formatting, date-format, date-formatting

```
LblExpirydate.Text = dataReader(0).ToString()
```

Output in asp.net form  : `01/05/2013 12:00:00 AM`

I want to change format to (`01/05/2013`)

Notes : My database

Column : `Expirydate`

data type : `Date`

Comment: what's that `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date to String with pattern problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203973/date-to-string-with-pattern-problem)

Answer (score 1):

You can format the string using .ToString() in several different ways:

```
dataReader(0).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");


dataReader(0).ToString("d");
```

The second option is better as it will format using the current locale. See this MSDN article for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Comment: LblExpirydate.Text = dataReader(0).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); This should give you what you need

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format.

Line 37:             LblExpirydate.Text = dataReader(0).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

Comment: when i make it 
LblExpirydate.Text = dataReader(0).ToString() 
Output :   01/05/2013 12:00:00 AM
I think this error according to convert date from database  to string at asp.net Form

Comment: is dataReader(0) definitely a DateTime? 

try: `LblExpirydate.Text = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", dataReader(0));`

It could be that it has already been converted to a string. If it is already a string then you can just use `LblExpirydate.Text = dataReader(0).Substring(0,10)`

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime thisDate1 =  DateTime.Now;
 Label1.Text =thisDate1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") ;
```

output:
03/30/2013

```
 DateTime thisDate1 =  DateTime.Now;
    Label1.Text =thisDate1.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") ;
```

output:
03-30-2013

```
DateTime thisDate1 =  DateTime.Now;
Label1.Text =thisDate1.ToString("MM,dd,yyyy") ;
```

output:
03,30,2013

```
DateTime thisDate1 =  DateTime.Now;
Label1.Text =thisDate1.ToString("MMMM,dd,yyyy") ;
```

output:
March,30,2013

and so on...